# .net reporting with text file (.txt)

Tags: asp.net

I have a text file for the report in my .net application. Now I need to download this text file so that user can open it in a nice format. Also I need to print this text file in a nice format too. I could convert this text file to word or excel for the nice format. But I am wondering if I have other choices. I never use reportview control. Is that a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

Report Viewer is used to display SQL Server Reporting Services reports.

You can use FileHelpers (http://www.filehelpers.com/) to load your text file into an object, as long as it is a comma delimited or fixed length file.  Then format the data anyway you want for display on a web page.